# Why is function rand in square brackets?

Tags: php

I cant figure out why is rand in square brackets in this case , everywhere I have checked it is in round ones. This is the code :

```
$characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

$allCharacters=$characters . strtolower($characters);


$pass="";

for($i=0; $i<strlen($allCharacters);$i++)

$pass.=$allCharacters[rand (0,strlen($allCharacters)-1)]  ;

echo $pass;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

`rand()` is a function but it is just written with a space, to become `rand ()`.

Here's an explanation:

```php
$pass .= $allCharacters[rand(0, strlen($allCharacters) - 1)];
```

What this line is doing is:

1. Find the length of `$allCharacters`.
2. Pick a random number between 0 and one less than that number (51, if you're using the alphabet capital + lower).
3. Use that randomly generated number as an **index** to `$allCharacters`. This is what the square brackets are. Just as you'd get the third item of a list with `$list[2]` (`$list[3 - 1]`), you can use a random number as well. Whoever wrote this code is simply passing the result of `rand()` directly into the index.
4. That index will select a random character from your list of every character and append it to `$pass`.

So, what you'll end up with is `$pass` holding 52 random letters from the alphabet.

Comment: Okay okay , i got it. I was thinking that you can use [ ] only for array index but yeah string is an array of letters. Makes sense. Thanks